# Version compatibility error with Application Enhancer

Tags: macos, code-injection

I am using Application enhancer on Mac OS X 10.6. I am getting version incompatibility error and plug in does not get loaded.

Error is as below

"MAC OS X version too new.
Beep Multiplier has not been tested on Mac OS X 10.6 and therefore will not be loaded."

Any Idea how to fix it!

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to add APESnowLeopardCertified key and set it to true.

Comment: how do you set the key to true?

Comment: We have to add a APESnowLeopardCertified key to plist and set that to true. Make sure key is boolean entry.